# ROI check function for sanity error, not checking bounds

Tags: r

Why do I get an error "check_function_for_sanity" when function y has parameter checks to stop if x values are less than 1?  When specifying the optimization problem I specifically give the variables' box constraints making the lower bound 2 for each x so the parameter check should never cause an error.  If I remove the parameter checks the program runs fine.

```r
library(ROI)
#> ROI: R Optimization Infrastructure
#> Registered solver plugins: nlminb, alabama, glpk, symphony.
#> Default solver: auto.

y <- function(x) {
    if (x[[1]] < 1) stop()
    if (x[[2]] < 1) stop()

    sum(-x^2)
}

nlp <- OP(maximum = TRUE,
          objective = F_objective(F = y, n = 2, names = c("x1", "x2")),
          bounds = V_bound(li = 1:2, lb = rep(2, 2), ub = rep(100, 2), nobj = 2))
#> Error in .check_function_for_sanity(F, n): cannot evaluate function 'F' using 'n' = 2 parameters.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>